# box2d 2.2 b2Body GetGroundBody method is gone

Tags: box2d

i try to fallow tutorial that is writen with old box2d < =2.1
i having problem to understand how to replace the GetGroundBody method of the b2Body
to box2d >= 2.2

```
var jointDef:b2MouseJointDef=new b2MouseJointDef();
jointDef.bodyA=world.GetGroundBody();   // what does it need to be now?
jointDef.bodyB=touchedBody;
jointDef.target=mouseToWorld();
jointDef.maxForce=1000*touchedBody.GetMass();
mouseJoint=world.CreateJoint(jointDef) as b2MouseJoint;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make your own static body to function as a ground body.